# problem with parse_ini_file

Tags: php

I'm using parse_ini_file() to read an ini file that has this line:

```
[admin]
hide_fields[] = ctr_ad_headerImg
```

the problem is that it outputs it like,

```
[admin]
hide_fields = Array
```

can someone help me out? how do I read "hide_fields[]" like a string?

Best Regards
Joricam

My code is:

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file($config_path, true);
//print_r($ini_array);
//echo $ini_array["default_colors"]["sitebg"];
$ini_array["default_colors"]["sitebg"]="#000000";
write_php_ini($ini_array,$config_path);
```

Functions that Im using:

```
function write_php_ini($array, $file)
{
    $res = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $val)
    {
        if(is_array($val))
        {
            $res[] = "[$key]";
            foreach($val as $skey => $sval) $res[] = "$skey = ".(is_numeric($sval) ? $sval : ''.$sval.'');
        }
        else $res[] = "$key = ".(is_numeric($val) ? $val : ''.$val.'');
    }
    safefilerewrite($file, implode("\r\n", $res));
}
//////
function safefilerewrite($fileName, $dataToSave)
{    if ($fp = fopen($fileName, 'w'))
    {
        $startTime = microtime();
        do
        {            $canWrite = flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
           // If lock not obtained sleep for 0 - 100 milliseconds, to avoid collision and CPU load
           if(!$canWrite) usleep(round(rand(0, 100)*1000));
        } while ((!$canWrite)and((microtime()-$startTime) < 1000));

        //file was locked so now we can store information
        if ($canWrite)
        {            fwrite($fp, $dataToSave);
            flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/parse_ini_file) does handle such identifiers. It correctly converts them into arrays on reading the ini file:

```
 print_r(parse_ini_string("hide_fields[] = ctr_ad_headerImg"));
```

Will generate:

```
Array
(
    [hide_fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => ctr_ad_headerImg
        )
```

The entry can be accessed as `$cfg["hide_fields"][0]` in PHP. The problem is that the ini file output function you have chosen *this time* does not understand `array` attributes.

Since you are probably interested in workarounds instead of using an appropriate tool, apply this conversion loop on your ini data:

```
// foreach ($sections ...) maybe

foreach ($cfg as $key=>$value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
         foreach ($value as $i=>$v) {
             $cfg["$key"."[$i]"] = $v;
         }
         unset($cfg[$key]);
    }
}
```

And save it afterwards.

---

### Edited code

```
function write_php_ini($array, $file)
{
    $res = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $val)
    {
        if(is_array($val))
        {
            $res[] = "[$key]";
            foreach($val as $skey => $sval) {
                if (is_array($sval)) {
                    foreach ($sval as $i=>$v) {
                        $res[] = "{$skey}[$i] = $v";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $res[] = "$skey = $sval";
                }
            }
        }
        else $res[] = "$key = $val";
    }
    safefilerewrite($file, implode("\r\n", $res));
}

//////
function safefilerewrite($fileName, $dataToSave)
{    
    file_put_contents($fileName, $dataToSave, LOCK_EX);    
}
```

Comment: this is a great awnser but I'm php blind almost, I'm a real noob, let me edit my original post with my code and functions, please guide me

Comment: Only if you promise that this is your very last .ini question.

Comment: it is, I promise, after this I'll have the application I was building complete! I also promise to not quit studying php here, I will read on further until I become an expert and fully understand all of whats hapenning with the code. I give you my word!

Comment: See rewritten code. It splits up the arrays into `key[123]=` entries. If you don't want the numeric index, then remove the `$i` there. Also took the liberty to cut down the pointless file saving function.

Comment: IT WORKS FULL OF AWESOMENESSSSSS :D dude thanks you soooo much! Can you suggeste me readings / book to fully understand whats happening with your code?

Comment: There's really only the php manual, and the language reference in particular http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php - be sure to download the manual http://www.php.net/download-docs.php, and browse through the function reference. That's the only way to get an overview.